# Running Jenkins slave on different OS than master (and host)

Tags: windows, unix, jenkins, docker

I'm trying to introduce continuous integration in an old project, and we've got quite specific situation - it's possible to put the CI server only on our test server that runs on CentOS. The server has quite a lot of unused RAM and CPU capability.

However, we need to run Ant builds on Windows (this also used to be how the project did packaging before), however it turned out that not the same output (after binary compare) is produced by just using Unix versions of Java and Ant.

I drew up a diagram of how in my mind it could work, but I'm really wondering whether that is even possible (with already given tools).

[image]

The black part is implemented, I'm curious whether the red part could be possible. Could the Jenkins slave communicate with master on different OS?

Comment: So you want to host a Windows VM on your CentOS instance?

Comment: @BrunoLavit Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

It *should* be possible. I have a feeling you will need to play with your network settings. But if before you start changing **anything** see if you can start a headless slave by following these directions: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machine

Answer (score 0):

Using [VirtualBox](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/VirtualBox) for CentOS, it will possible to run a Windows VM on your CentOS host.

I'm not sure you need Docker to launch your Jenkins slave.

It maybe better to use a [standard JNLP Windows service](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service) to connect your Windows slave to Dockerised Jenkins master.

If the master is not able to view the Windows node using this method, you may have to tweak your network configuration on the Windows VM.

But I'm not sure it's necessary.